# Ruby Beginner: Can't Get Created Methods To Work

Tags: ruby, methods

Using

- Ruby 2.1.4
- Mac OSX 10.9.5
- Text Wrangler
- Terminal

Working on this problem:
"Create a class called Car. Give it a method called new_car which will return an empty array. (This array symbolizes a new car that is being built in a factory.) Then, create a method that takes the empty array returned by the blank_array method and adds some important car part to that array, and returns the new array. Then, create a method that takes that new array, and adds yet something else to it, etc. Do this until you have a total of five methods. So by the end, you should have one method that will end up returning an array that holds four car parts. (Like: ["engine", "wheels", "radio", "cupholder"] )"

So I created a class and threw some methods in there so I could "build" a car. I loaded the class into irb and created a variable named `newcar` by writing `newcar = Car.new`. When I type `newcar.new_car` ruby returns the empty array. However when I call any of the other methods I get ths error message:

`NameError: undefined local variable or method`car' for #
    from car.rb:9:in `add_wheels'
    from (irb):5
    from /UserName.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.4/bin/irb:11:in`'`

```
class Car

  def new_car
    car = []
    return car
  end

  def add_wheels
    car << "wheels"
    return car
  end

  def add_axels
    car << "axels"
    return car
  end

  def add_engine
    car << "engine"
    return car
  end

  def add_radio
    car << "radio"
    return car
  end
end
```

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope the code you've written is for learning purpose. As none of its bits makes any sense to me.

The error you're getting is because `car` array which you have defined in `new_car` method is local and won't be available to other instance methods. For that you need to use [`attr_accessor`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Module.html#method-i-attr_accessor) to make `car` to be available as instance method which can be used for reading and writing instance variable like so:

```
class Car

  attr_accessor :car

  def new_car
    @car = []
  end

  def add_wheels
    car << "wheels"
    return car
  end

  def add_axels
    car << "axels"
    return car
  end

  def add_engine
    car << "engine"
    return car
  end

  def add_radio
    car << "radio"
    return car
  end
end

newcar = Car.new

newcar.new_car
puts newcar.add_wheels
#=> 'wheels'
```

Note that `@car = []` in `new_car` method. That defines the instance variable `@car` with an empty array, which can be accessed by reader method `car` and writer method `car<<` or `car=` in the code later.

Also, having your instance variables initialized like `@car = []`, is a good place for `initialize` method, not `new_car`:

```
def initialize
  @car = []
end
```

So, when you call `Car.new`, it will call `initialize` method and your variable `@car = []` will be initialized by default.

Comment: One thing. Why are you using `@car` only in `new_car` and accessors everywhere else? Is there any specific reason? If so, state it in the answer. If not  - mention there's none =) ...and this might be a good place to introduce `initialize`.

Comment: @D-side : I think you didn't read the Note at the bottom, I clearly mentioned why `@car` is in `new_car`. Of course it'll be good to have initialize method, OP is more concerned why the error is undefined local variable of method `car` in program.

Comment: I read it before asking, it's a quite tricky part of Ruby. I thought `attr_accessor` was to define methods that modified a corresponding instance variable (`:car` for `@car`, and it's actually true), and using `@car` directly afterwards is pointless. I was supposing using just `car = []` would work (by calling `car=`) but it turns out, that it creates a local variable instead. Huh.

Comment: Using `attr_accessor` makes `@car` readable and writable outside the class, which may not be desirable. Saying you "need to use" it is also incorrect.

Comment: Umm... Corrected the explanation. Thanks.

Comment: The problem with this answer is that it strongly recommends ("...you _need_ to use...") using `attr_accessor` to access an instance variable _within the instance_ (when its intended purpose is to make an instance variable accessible _outside_ the instance). There is no "need" for `attr_accessor` here and using it could undesirably reduce encapsulation. The proper, idiomatic solution would be to use instance variables everywhere.

Comment: Learn to read between the lines. The complete sentence is: *"For that you need to use"* Which means, to achieve what you're(OP) trying to do can happen if you had used this. That's all.

Comment: I don't see any indication in the op that `@car` needs to be accessed outside the class. Your code would allow `Car.new.car=nil` for example. That seems like an undesirable side effect.

Comment: That's why I said: *"I hope the code you've written is for learning purpose. "* Also, talk about undesirable side effect, won't you know what you're doing if you do `Car.new.car=nil`?? If you'd still be wondering what got wrong after writing such code then there are more other stuffs that you need to fix before fixing the code.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/64579/discussion-between-max-and-user089247).

Answer (score -1):

You're writing *instance methods*, so you need to use an *instance variable* in order for them to all access the same array. Just replace all of your `car` variables with `@car`.

```
class Car
  def new_car
    @car = []
  end

  def add_wheels
    @car << "wheels"
  end
  # etc...
```

Comment: First op has not defined any instance methods, second even if op decides to define an instance variable, calling `car <<` won't work. At the end you'll have to make your own writer method or use attr_writer at least. Third, as a ruby beginner op won't understand what you're trying to say unless you give an example explaining things. Forth, without an example the answer is as better as a comment.

Comment: To be more clear, when I say: not defined any instance methods. I meant `car` or `car<<`.

Comment: First, he is defining instance methods: `def add_wheels` defines an instance method, etc. I said to replace _every_ `car` with `@car` i.e. `@car <<`, which would work. You do not _have_ to use `attr_writer` or `attr_accessor` to modify an instance variable _within the class_. You can just access the variable directly.

Comment: Also please explain what is technically incorrect with my answer.

Comment: 2. You should explain why code didn't work, and how could it have worked with slight modification(if possible, of course) instead of throwing off them to a different approach(which should be given only when the presented code/approach is completely wrong or not possible to fix). This gives One of thoughts to asker: A: Probably the tutorial/project code was wrong. B: Probably something was extra done to make that approach work. Which leaves asker with one doubt: *Why my code didn't work, when the other code I saw was working?*.

Comment: 3. It's always better to tell asker how something could have been done. If you also tell them how something can be fixed, especially a beginner, they learn something new. If you look at your answer, it doesn't really give away anything new to beginner to learn.

Comment: I don't see what my answer has to do with a downvote that your answer received.

Comment: You needed an explanation, I gave 3, explaining each and everything in detail. I am not sure why you'd bring "downvote" stuff specifically.